# Angular Material: mat-select not selecting default

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have a mat-select where the options are all objects defined in an array.  I am trying to set the value to default to one of the options, however it is being left selected when the page renders.

My typescript file contains:

```
  public options2 = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "a"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "b"}
  ]
  public selected2 = this.options2[1].id;
```

My HTML file contains:

```
  <div>
    <mat-select
        [(value)]="selected2">
      <mat-option
          *ngFor="let option of options2"
          value="{{ option.id }}">
        {{ option.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
```

I have tried setting `selected2` and the `value` in `mat-option` to both the object and its id, and have tried using both `[(value)]` and `[(ngModel)]` in the `mat-select`, but none are working.

I am using material version 2.0.0-beta.10

Comment: Use `compareWith`. It's more elegant.

Comment: MUST HAVE `compareWith`, see badis answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333171/angular-material-mat-select-not-selecting-default#answer-50049506

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Use a binding for the value in your template.

```
value="{{ option.id }}"
```

should be

```
[value]="option.id"
```

And in your selected value use `ngModel` instead of `value`.

```
<mat-select [(value)]="selected2">
```

should be

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected2">
```

Complete code:

```
<div>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected2">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options2" [value]="option.id">{{ option.name }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</div>
```

---

On a side note as of [version 2.0.0-beta.12](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) the [material select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) now accepts a `mat-form-field` element as the parent element so it is consistent with the other material input controls. Replace the `div` element with `mat-form-field` element after you upgrade.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected2">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options2" [value]="option.id">{{ option.name }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: "It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7.
    
    For more information on this, see our API docs here:
    https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel"

Comment: @ldgorman - I don't see how you are drawing that conclusion. If you are referring to [`mat-form-field`](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field), this is `..."used to wrap several Angular Material components and apply common Text field styles"`, so not the same thing. Other than that the OP and also my answer made no mention `FormControl`, `FormGroup`, or `FormControlName`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue even after implementing the same code as above @Igor

Comment: @Chuck - If you are still having problems please ask a new question and include an [mcve]. If you want me to take a look you can reply to this comment with a link to that question.

Comment: @Igor- We figured it out, the value was being returned as a number and the Mat-select it looking for a string. `[compareWith]` directive is what we used

Comment: Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7. This answer does not work anymore. Please define it as being supported max till v6 or remove

Comment: @axelrotter - there is no mention of using a reactive form directive in this question or the answer. The answer works fine as is.

Comment: @Igor you are right. It doesn't work for Template Driven forms either.

Comment: @axelrotter - Using `ngModel` does work and is supported in template driven forms which is what the question is asking about and the answer illustrates. See also https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hym5rd which shows that the above would work using the latest version 8.1 (as of writing this comment).

Comment: Why does it have to be ` [(ngModel)]="selected2" ` instead of ` [(ngModel)]="this.options2[1].id" ` ?

Answer (score 158):

Use `compareWith`, A function to compare the option values with the selected values. see here: https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect

For an object of the following structure:

```
listOfObjs = [{ name: 'john', id: '1'}, { name: 'jimmy', id: '2'},...]
```

Define markup like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select
    [compareWith]="compareObjects"
    [(ngModel)]="obj">
       <mat-option  *ngFor="let obj of listOfObjs" [value]="obj">
          {{ obj.name }}
       </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And define comparison function like this:

```
compareObjects(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
  return o1.name === o2.name && o1.id === o2.id;
}
```

Comment: Perfect when dealing with objects and not simple arrays. Thank you.

Comment: ngModel is deprecated now, so we have to use formControlName, but the solution of using a comparator-function still works in Angular 16

Answer (score 27):

I'm using Angular 5 and reactive forms with mat-select and couldn't get either of the above solutions to display the initial value.

I had to add [compareWith] to deal with the different types being used within the mat-select component. Internally, it appears mat-select uses an array to hold the selected value. This is likely to allow the same code to work with multiple selections if that mode is turned on.

[Angular Select Control Doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#caveat-option-selection)

Here's my solution:

Form Builder to initialize the form control:

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    country: new FormControl([ this.myRecord.country.id ] ),
    ...
});
```

Then implement the compareWith function on your component:

```
compareIds(id1: any, id2: any): boolean {
    const a1 = determineId(id1);
    const a2 = determineId(id2);
    return a1 === a2;
}
```

Next create and export the determineId function (I had to create a standalone function so mat-select could use it):

```
export function determineId(id: any): string {
    if (id.constructor.name === 'array' && id.length > 0) {
       return '' + id[0];
    }
    return '' + id;
}
```

Finally add the compareWith attribute to your mat-select:

```
<mat-form-field hintLabel="select one">
<mat-select placeholder="Country" formControlName="country" 
    [compareWith]="compareIds">

    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">
                        {{ country.name }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 22):

You should be binding it as `[value]` in the `mat-option` as below,

```
<mat-select placeholder="Panel color" [(value)]="selected2">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options2" [value]="option.id">
    {{ option.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/VPt2vEtphQWb9MoLB7Kv?p=preview)**

Comment: This works perfectly.

Insted of using ngModel or setValue() this is easiest and perfect method

Answer (score 13):

You can simply implement your own compare function

`[compareWith]="compareItems"`

See as well the [docu](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api). So the complete code would look like:

```
  <div>
    <mat-select
        [(value)]="selected2" [compareWith]="compareItems">
      <mat-option
          *ngFor="let option of options2"
          value="{{ option.id }}">
        {{ option.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
```

and in the Typescript file:

```
  compareItems(i1, i2) {
    return i1 && i2 && i1.id===i2.id;
  }
```

Comment: This is worked for me and I think this is mostly correct way but if list contain only one element it is not working. Thanks

Comment: What kind of exception you get with just one element? Cuz the compare should take into charge if `i1` or `i2` won't exist.

Answer (score 9):

As already mentioned in Angular 6 using ngModel in reactive forms is deprecated (and removed in Angular 7), so I modified the template and the component as following.

The template:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [formControl]="filter" multiple 
                [compareWith]="compareFn">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let v of values" [value]="v">{{v.label}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The main parts of the component (`onChanges` and other details are omitted):

```
interface SelectItem {
    label: string;
    value: any;
}

export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {
    filter = new FormControl();

    @Input
    selected: SelectItem[] = [];

    @Input()
    values: SelectItem[] = [];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.filter.setValue(this.selected);
    }

    compareFn(v1: SelectItem, v2: SelectItem): boolean {
        return compareFn(v1, v2);
    }
}

function compareFn(v1: SelectItem, v2: SelectItem): boolean {
    return v1 && v2 ? v1.value === v2.value : v1 === v2;
}
```

Note **this.filter.setValue(this.selected)** in `ngOnInit` above.

It seems to work in Angular 6.

Comment: This should actually be the best answer, since this is also covering object selections when dealing with two different API results to compare.

Comment: (e.g. Total list of items to select from and selected item within another api call).

Comment: Angular 7 still works with templated driven models! But you cannot mix it with reactive forms on the same templated. Your hint with the `[compareWith]` was great

Answer (score 9):

I had problem in binding first option, when page load. Below has the solution which helped me

**.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">    
    <mat-select #teamDropdown 
        [ngModel]="selectedGroupId" (selectionChange)="selectedGroupId=$event.value">
        <mat-option value=undefined>Please Select</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let grp of groups" [value]="grp.groupsId">
            {{grp.groupName}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**.ts**

```
@ViewChild('teamDropdown') teamDropdown: MatSelect;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.teamDropdown.options.first.select();
    });
}
```

Comment: You mean: this.teamDropdown .options.first.select();

Answer (score 3):

I did it just like in these examples. Tried to set the value of the mat-select to the value of one of the mat-options. But failed.

My mistake was to do [(value)]="someNumberVariable" to a numeric type variable while the ones in mat-options were strings. Even if they looked the same in the template it would not select that option.

Once I parsed the someNumberVariable to a string everything was totally fine.

So it seems you need to have the mat-select and the mat-option values not only be the same number (if you are presenting numbers) but also let them be of type string.

Comment: That was my issue, too. One was numeric, the other one was a string.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select #monedaSelect  formControlName="monedaDebito" [attr.disabled]="isLoading" [placeholder]="monedaLabel | async ">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let moneda of monedasList" [value]="moneda.id">{{moneda.detalle}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('monedaSelect') public monedaSelect: MatSelect;
this.genericService.getOpciones().subscribe(res => {

  this.monedasList = res;
  this.monedaSelect._onChange(res[0].id);


});
```

Using object: {id: number, detalle: string}

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
this.selectedObjectList = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}]
this.allObjectList = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}, {id:5}]
let newList = this.allObjectList.filter(e => this.selectedObjectList.find(a => e.id == a.id))
this.selectedObjectList = newList
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is little tricky and simpler.

```
<div>
    <mat-select
        [placeholder]="selected2">
      <mat-option
          *ngFor="let option of options2"
          value="{{ option.id }}">
        {{ option.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
```

I just made use of the **placeholder**. The default color of material placeholder is `light gray`. To make it look like the option is selected, I just manipulated the CSS as follows:

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-placeholder {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Binding or setting of default value works only if the **value** attribute on **MatSelect** is comparable to **value** attribute binded to **MatOption**. If you bind `caption` of your item to **value** attribute of **mat-option** element you must set the default element on **mat-select** to `caption` of your item too. If you bind `Id` of your item to **mat-option**, you must bind `id` to **mat-select** too, not a whole item, caption or any other, only the same field.

But you need to do it with binding []

Answer (score 1):

I followed the above very carefully and still couldn't get the initial value selected.

The reason was that although my bound value was defined as a string in typescript, my backend API was returning a number.

Javascript loose typing simply changed the type at runtime (without error), which prevented selection the of the initial value.

Component

```
myBoundValue: string;
```

Template

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="myBoundValue">
```

Solution was to update the API to return a string value.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to achieve this is using a `formControl` with a default value, inside a `FormGroup` (optional) for example. This is an example using an unit selector to an area input:

ts

```
H_AREA_UNIT = 1;
M_AREA_UNIT = 2;

exampleForm: FormGroup;

this.exampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  areaUnit: [this.H_AREA_UNIT],
});
```

html

```
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm">
 <mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Unit</mat-label>
   <mat-select formControlName="areaUnit">
     <mat-option [value]="H_AREA_UNIT">h</mat-option>
     <mat-option [value]="M_AREA_UNIT">m</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**The only solution is that your form control or Ng Model value inside mat select tag must match the text assigned to value in option tags** Here it is
Ts file

```
selectedFood = 'Tacos';
```

Template

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Favorite Food</mat-label>
      <mat-select [(value)]="selectedFood">
        <mat-option value=''>---------</mat-option>
<mat-option value='Tacos'>Tacos</mat-option>
<mat-option value='Pizza'>Pizza</mat-option>
        
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <p>You selected: {{selectedFood}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A comparison between a number and a string use to be false**, so, cast you selected value to a string within ngOnInit and it will work.

I had same issue, I filled the mat-select with an enum, using

```
Object.keys(MyAwesomeEnum).filter(k => !isNaN(Number(k)));
```

and I had the enum value I wanted to select...

I spent few hours struggling my mind trying to identify why it wasn't working. And I did it just after rendering all the variables being used in the mat-select, the keys collection and the selected... if you have ["0","1","2"] and you want to select 1 (which is a number) **1=="1" is false and because of that nothing is selected.**

so, the **solution** is to **cast you selected value to a string** within ngOnInit and it will work.

Comment: Hi Juan you may want to look at this post which goes into the details about different equality operators in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: Hi William, that's a great post, I've been there few times... And I learnt how to properly compare (I hope, and I always can review the doc) ... The problem here was that the bindings, forced by the material controller, where using different types, number and strings... That controller expects to have same types, so, if selected is a number, the collection must be a collection of numbers... That was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

TS

```
   optionsFG: FormGroup;
   this.optionsFG = this.fb.group({
       optionValue: [null, Validators.required]
   });

   this.optionsFG.get('optionValue').setValue(option[0]); //option is the arrayName
```

HTML

```
   <div class="text-right" [formGroup]="optionsFG">
     <mat-form-field>
         <mat-select placeholder="Category" formControlName="optionValue">
           <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options;let i =index" [value]="option">
            {{option.Value}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
public options2 = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "a"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "b"}
]
 
YourFormGroup = FormGroup; 
mode: 'create' | 'update' = 'create';

constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private defaults: defautValuesCpnt,
      private fb: FormBuilder,
      private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}
  
ngOnInit() {

  if (this.defaults) {
    this.mode = 'update';
  } else {
    this.defaults = {} as Cpnt;
  }

  this.YourFormGroup.patchValue({
    ...
    fCtrlName: this.options2.find(x => x.name === this.defaults.name).id,
    ... 
  });

  this.YourFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    fCtrlName: [ , Validators.required]
  });

}
```

```html
  <div>
    <mat-select formControlName="fCtrlName"> <mat-option
          *ngFor="let option of options2"
          value="{{ option.id }}">
        {{ option.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
```

Comment: This will help when you're using Edit & Update in the safe component,