# how to keep a value selected in mat-select angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components

I had used a mat-select component in my project, for which the code is:

```
        <div class="col-md-6">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Select Job" formControlName="job_instruction_id" [(value)]="jifId">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let jif of jifList" [value]="jif.id">
            {{jif.id}}.....{{ jif.jif_no }} ---- {{ jif.job_name }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

the `jifId` holds value `1` at the moment, and the mat option values are `1` and `2`, but still the first option is not pre selected when the page loads.

Comment: while initialize your reactive form, initialize `job_instruction_id` with value of `1`(mention the data type).

Comment: This might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650790/set-default-option-in-mat-select/50651134#50651134)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **`[(ngModel)]`**

```
<mat-select placeholder="Select Job" formControlName="job_instruction_id" [(ngModel)]="jifId">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let jif of jifList" value={{jif.id}}>
            {{jif.id}}.....{{ jif.jif_no }} ---- {{ jif.job_name }}
        </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using form Control use the `setValue` option from the component.

```
this.form.controls['job_instruction_id'].setValue(this.jifId);
```