# Angular 6: mat-table [dataSource] renders only first record from data array

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I want to list a records in `mat-table` format. My array of data is as below in this screenshot.

[image]

As seen in the image console log it has two records but in table listing it displays only first record.

Here is my component in which i am getting records from the api services. As i am getting records through the `array.map()` so i am pushing the records into the array variable and have called my function into `ngAfterViewInit()` life cycle method.

```
export class RecordComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name',];
  data = [];
  recordList: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recordList = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getRecordListList();
  }

  getRecordListList() {
    var Arr = []
    this.recordList.data = [];
    this.apiService.getProductId(this.params.id).subscribe((response:any) => {
      let data = response.data[0]
      let productData = data.design_product
      productData.map((productid) => {
        this.apiService.getSelectedProductById(productid.selected_product_id).subscribe((response:any) => {
          if(response.data !== null) {
            Arr.push(response.data[0])
            this.recordList = Arr
            this.data = Arr;
            console.log(this.recordList) // line no 59 as displayed in the screenshot
          }
        })
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML component.

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="recordList">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Sr No</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index"> {{i+1}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Comment: Hi, i am having the same issue. Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(response.data !== null) { 
  this.data = response.data;
  this.recordList = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
}
```

Comment: That is not working... have already declared this in ```ngOnInit()``` life cycle method.

Comment: okay you can remove that line. what you are getting in this.data?

Comment: Please review the screenshot in question description, that same record i am getting the ```this.data```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @Mustafa: can you please explain me what are you saying exactly ? I can not get your point.

Comment: @aananddham, you have suggested some code here as an answer. You need to explain  why the code you suggest here answers the question. Down the line this context will be useful for someone reading your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged generally.

Comment: @Mustafa, sir i have not not suggested any answer code; that is suggested by other user.

Comment: @aananddham, my first comment was directed and the person posting the question, but since you asked me to explain my comment I assumed you were that person. My bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212249/discussion-between-aananddham-and-mustafa).