# Set default value for mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-select. when I first show the form I want it to select the first item in the select after the data is loaded. How can I do this?

```
  <mat-select 
          placeholder="period"
          (selectionChange)="selectperiod($event)"
          (ngModel)="(periodoptions)"
        >
          <mat-option
            *ngFor="let p of periodoptions | async"
            [value]="p.periodid"
          >
            {{ p.periodstart }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
```

using this to call function to pull rest data

```
 of(this.getperiods()).subscribe(pp => {
      this.periodoptions = pp;
```

Comment: I think you should look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650790/set-default-option-in-mat-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use ngModel, just replace ***(ngModel)*** by ***[(ngModel)]***.
You can also replace the *ngModel* by *[(value)]* to avoid using the ngModel module.

Also, assign *periodoptions* to the ngModel is wrong if you want to select the first item of the array, since each mat-option value is *p.periodid*. You will have to use ***periodoptions[0].periodid*** instead

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you:

```
<mat-select placeholder="period" (selectionChange)="selectperiod($event)" [(ngModel)]="periodoptions">
    <mat-option>Default Option</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let p of periodoptions | async" [value]="p.periodid">
        {{ p.periodstart }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```