# How to display years in dropdown using array Angular

Tags: angular

I have here this function in my service.ts

```
   public getUploadPeriod(){
    let baseYear = 2020;
    let currYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    let years = [];

    for (var i = baseYear; i <= currYear; i++) {
    years.push(i);
    }
    return years
  
  }
```

And this is the ts of my project I am trying to call out the function that I create in service.ts

```
  getUploadPeriod() {
   const years = this.uploadFacilityService.getUploadPeriod();
   console.log(years)
   return years
  }
```

And this is my html

```
   <mat-select
    placeholder="Select Time Period">
    <mat-option  value="">
        {{ years }}
    </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
```

The years are already generated with the function that I created but theres no display in my dropdown list. Can someone help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: you should use a [ngfor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) in this case. Please spend some time on the [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) tutorial

Comment: you are not looping over the array, check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451748/2429434

Answer (score 2):

As seen in the documentation for the Angular select:

> To add options to the select, add `<mat-option>` elements to the
> `<mat-select>`. Each `<mat-option>` has a value property that can be used
> to set the value that will be selected if the user chooses this
> option. The content of the `<mat-option>` is what will be shown to the
> user.

Remember that inside a select, the options must be generated iteratively if you want to fetch them from a collection. Thus, in your useCase, it would look like this:

```
<mat-label>Select time period</mat-label>
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="year" name="year">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year">
    {{year}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Read more about select and `<mat-select>`: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

**Edit:** After taking a look at the rest of your code, `years` should have a higher scope than the one you are giving it. So, initialize the variable in the component constructor and set its value inside of your method (remember to set `this.years`). This way, the variable will be accessible from the component's template.

Comment: Thank you so much this works on my project. will delete this post on a certain time. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi! follow up question, How can I arrange the order of the years in the dropdown like it should be 2022-2020.

Comment: The Array.prototype.sort() method is good place to start. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort If you have a more specific situation, maybe Array.protoype.map() is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`years` variable should be declared outside of method scope so template would have access to it.

```js
years: any;

  getUploadPeriod() {
    this.years = this.serviceGetUploadPeriod();
    console.log(this.years);
  }
```

Use `*ngFor` to iterate over items in template.

```html
<div *ngFor="let year of years">
  {{ year }}
</div>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4qd3ao?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Please do not delete the question just because you got your answer. Someone else might come over this problem too - leave this here for future readers. For sorting, sort the items in the array in TS file beforehand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063027/15439733