# automatic select drop down option

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an issue,I have a drop down list inside a select area,the problem is when the component is loaded, by default the first option in the list is selected and a content is shown, but this content is not updated, it's get updated when we select again the same option selected first.here is my template.

```
<mat-form-field class="style-select">
            <mat-select name="structureTypes" #ctrl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="MasStruc">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let master of masterList" (click)="onSelect($event)" [value]="master">
                    {{master}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

here is two image corresponding to the issue:

[image]

Here the input FWT is automatically selected the first time when I open the component,but the list below is not updated,in order to update it we need to select again the same option manually second time.

here is a image:

[image]

I think to make a placeholder by default ask the user to select an option,but i want to share that with you if there is other way to select again automatically an option when we load the component the first time.

Comment: look at this links it will help you select by default values
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650790/set-default-option-in-mat-select/50651042
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333171/angular-material-mat-select-not-selecting-default

let me know if need more help about this

Answer (score 0):

Am making my suggestion as far as I understood. I'm providing solution for both, selecting a value by default as well as having a place holder. please check them.

HTML:

```
 <mat-form-field class="style-select">
   <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
   <mat-select name="structureTypes" #ctrl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="MasStruc">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let master of masterList" [value]="master">
        {{master}}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
 <br>
 <mat-form-field class="style-select">
   Selected by default
   <mat-select name="structureTypes" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let master of masterList" [value]="master">
        {{master}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
masterList = [
   "option1",
   "option2"
];
selectedValue: string = this.masterList[1];
```

Let me know if I got your question wrong.

Comment: no that's not what i want,this is give 2 drop down area,i want a single drop down but when i load the component the option FWT...is selected again in order to update the content of the table below.

Comment: can you share your code via stackblitz. so I can go through them and help you.