# Angular Form nested objects

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I have a form where the user enters some data, then sends a POST. Now I am working on a feature to allow editing of previously entered information. Some of the inputs in the fields have nested objects, as:

```
export class Transfer {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public destination: string,
        public market: string,
        public project: Project,
        public workstream: Workstream,
        public contact: Contact
    )
}
```

```
export class Workstream {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public workStream: string
    ) { }
}
```

```
export class Contact {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public name: string
    ) { }
}
```

When loading the information to the form, fields containing strings or numbers work well, but objects don't show the correct information. The field for Contact gives me a [object Object], while Workstream does not preselect the right option from a drop down.

```
            <!-- Workstream -->
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-label>Workstream</mat-label>
                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="transfer.workstream" name="workstream" [(value)]="transfer.workstream">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let workstream of workstreams$ | async" [value]="workstream">
                        {{workstream.workStream}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <!-- Contact -->
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Contact" [(ngModel)]="transfer.contact" name="contact" value="transfer.contact.name"
                #contactSearchBox (input)="searchContact(contactSearchBox.value)" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let contact of contacts$ | async" [value]="contact.name"
                    (click)="selectContact(contact)">
                    {{contact.name}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
```

In the contact field the user is able to search by name, which works.
Any clues on how to implement this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`mat-option` should have a string value. So the binding`[value]="workstream"`, should be changed to `[value]="workstream.workStream"`. This should work. However, if you need an entire object to be stored, then you should go with autocomplete component to store the entire object as a model in the form, and use `viewFormatter` function to display only the fields that you want (in the autocomplete results or the shown selected object).

Comment: I still get the same result. But I will investigate using autocomplete, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed both issues, thanks to [Badis Merabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333171/angular-material-mat-select-not-selecting-default) and [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview).

To fix my drop down, I added `[compareWith]="compareObjects"` to `mat-select`, and used the same function described in the link.

My search bar was fixed by adding `[displayWith]="displayFn"` to `mat-autocomplete`, using the same technique as done in Angular Material.